# Implementation of CAS for c, openmp

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I'm trying to implement the compare and swap operation so that my threads know whether or not to enter a particular region based on a value `u_parent`. I just want to know if this is the correct way to implement it and if I am going wrong somewhere.

```
int *u_parent;
u_parent = &graph->parents[u]; 

if (*u_parent < 0) { 
    // This region should only be entered by each thread
    // if the value of u_parent is < -1.   

    graph->parents[u] = v;
    // ^-- If region is entered, this value is modified
    // by some variable v

    //Swap:
    u_parent = &graph->parents[u];

    DO_SOMETHING();
}
```

Is this implementation correct because I am still seeing other threads enter this region after the CAS operation?

Comment: Wrong thinking. CAS is a *primitive* operation, above which multi-threading is built

Comment: If using OpenMP is a given for your situation--and you don't want to involve another specification or standard for threading to get atomic features--it seems [OpenMP has its own atomic operations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798010/what-is-the-difference-between-atomic-and-critical-in-openmp) you might use.

Answer (score 5):

> I'm trying to implement the compare and swap operation

You **cannot** implement that in C. Such an operation has to be [atomic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) to be meaningfully usable for synchronization purposes between threads. Be aware of [sequence points](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence_point) and [memory models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_model_(programming)).

Some compilers provide a builtin for that. (See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2975485/841108) question). Recent GCC provide [atomic builtins](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html#g_t_005f_005fatomic-Builtins) including `__atomic_compare_exchange` which generally gets compiled into a *single* machine code instruction. Read the wikipage on [compare-and-swap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap)

On Linux, be also aware of [futex(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/futex.7.html). With machine instructions like [CMPXCHG](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/CMPXCHG.html) they are the building blocks of many [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html) operations (so require some assembler code). Read also a good [pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/). The C11 standard (read [n1570](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html)) provides [`<stdatomic.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic) (in practice, the standard atomic operations are builtin to the compiler, or uses existing builtins).

Study also the source code of existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) C standard libraries, e.g. GNU [glibc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) or [musl-libc](https://musl-libc.org/). You'll see that many synchronization primitives are built above futexes, assembler code, and/or compiler builtins.

Also, [OpenMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) (when it is implemented by the compiler) is changing the behavior of the compiler (and of course of the generated executable).